# I don´t get why my class is mapped as complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to display information from a user-defined function in ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor. The function in the database looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetReportsByController(@controller_account VARCHAR(128))
RETURNS @retReports table (
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    ProviderID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    VertragID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Leistungszeitraum_von DATE NOT NULL,
    Leistungszeitraum_bis DATE NOT NULL,
    ReportklasseID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Version INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(64)
)
AS
BEGIN
    //Do some stuff and insert in the ret-table
        RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Entity Framework mapped this in this class:

```
public partial class udf_GetReportsByController_Result
{
    [Column("ID")]        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column("ProviderID")]
    public string ProviderID { get; set; }
    [Column("VertragID")]
    public int VertragID { get; set; }
    [Column("Leistungszeitraum_von")]
    public System.DateTime Leistungszeitraum_von { get; set; }
    [Column("Leistungszeitraum_bis")]
    public System.DateTime Leistungszeitraum_bis { get; set; }
    [Column("ReportklasseID")]
    public string ReportklasseID { get; set; }
    [Column("Version")]
    public int Version { get; set; }
    [Column("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to do some DbSet-Methods in my Controller, I get an Error message, that my model class is mapped as complex Type. I read that a complex type has no primary key, but I defined one in my function, and I need to address an element by it´s ID. How can I specify the primary key in this ret-Table?

Comment: How is the class wired to your dbcontext?

Comment: In my context I have the attribute ´public DbSet<udf_GetReportsByController_Result> reportSet { get; set; }´
and a method, which calls the database-function and returns an IQueryable<udf_getReportsByController_Result>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do something like

```
context.Set<udf_GetReportsByController_Result>()
```

Entity Framework will look for a table that is mapped against the result type. However, this table doesn't exist. The function does return a table, but this is a table variable, not a table that's part of the database schema. Only entity types are mapped against schema tables.

You can only get `udf_GetReportsByController_Result` objects by calling the imported function:

```
var results = context.udf_GetReportsByController(accountNo);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already know this, in my Controller I use this to make a list:
`result = db.udf_GetReportsByController(acc);`
But if you click on a certain element in the table I want to get this specific element in my Controller, like:
`Report rep = result.Find(id)`
or something you can do with normal entity types. 
Is there any way to get a specific element by it's ID?

Comment: You can get the results from the function and then you can apply further filters if necessary. Not `Find` though. You can do `results.FirstOrDefault(...)`, but `Find` is a complex function based on `DbSet` and cached entities, none of which apply to function results.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I handled the problem like you told me, using an IQueryable object.
I find my specific report by using LINQ
`result.any(r => r.ID == id(parameter));`